# Fur texture appears coarsely on Bunny

Tags: qt, opengl, graphics, 3d, texture-mapping

I wrote this code to apply texture to the bunny model provided in ply format. Bunny gets drawn with the texture, but instead of looking like fur, the texture looks like coarse points.

```
void GLRenderer::paintGL()
{
    // Set light
    GLfloat light_position[] = { lightPositionX, lightPositionY, lightPositionZ, 0.0 };
    glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Enabling texture
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

    bindTexture(QImage("fur4.bmp"));

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

        for( int i = 0 ; i < objPLYParser.g_vpX.size() ; i+=3 )
        {
                float vector1[3], vector2[3], vCross[3], normalizationValue;
                vector1[0] = objPLYParser.g_vpX[i] - objPLYParser.g_vpX[i+1];
                vector1[1] = objPLYParser.g_vpY[i] - objPLYParser.g_vpY[i+1];
                vector1[2] = objPLYParser.g_vpZ[i] - objPLYParser.g_vpZ[i+1];

                vector2[0] = objPLYParser.g_vpX[i] - objPLYParser.g_vpX[i+2];
                vector2[1] = objPLYParser.g_vpY[i] - objPLYParser.g_vpY[i+2];
                vector2[2] = objPLYParser.g_vpZ[i] - objPLYParser.g_vpZ[i+2];

                // Cross product
                vCross[0] = vector1[1] * vector2[2] - vector2[1] * vector1[2];
                vCross[1] = vector2[0] * vector1[2] - vector1[0] * vector2[2];
                vCross[2] = vector1[0] * vector2[1] - vector2[0] * vector1[1];

                // Value to do normalization with
                normalizationValue = sqrt( vCross[0]*vCross[0] + vCross[1]*vCross[1] + vCross[2]*vCross[2] );

                 float normal[3];
                 normal[0] = vCross[0]/normalizationValue;
                 normal[1] = vCross[1]/normalizationValue;
                 normal[2] = vCross[2]/normalizationValue;

                 glNormal3f(normal[0],normal[1],normal[2]);

            glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
            glVertex3f(objPLYParser.g_vpX[i],objPLYParser.g_vpY[i],objPLYParser.g_vpZ[i]);

            glTexCoord2f( 1.0,0.0);
            glVertex3f(objPLYParser.g_vpX[i+1],objPLYParser.g_vpY[i+1],objPLYParser.g_vpZ[i+1]);

            glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
            glVertex3f(objPLYParser.g_vpX[i+2],objPLYParser.g_vpY[i+2],objPLYParser.g_vpZ[i+2]);
        }


    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Texture files i tried :

[image]

[image]

Output I got :

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions what I might be doing wrong here ?

Comment: Are you sure the bunny have texture coordinates ?

Comment: @concept3d I am sorry, I dint get what you asked ?

Comment: What I asked, is explained better in the answer, you need to UV map your bunny, in other words give it texture coordinates using some 3D program (or generate them).

Comment: @concept3d Any resources I can refer for generating them ? All I can find is how to map textures onto dumb cubes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In these lines:

```
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
...

glTexCoord2f( 1.0,0.0);
...

glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
...
```

You supply texture coordinates which map half the entire texture to every individual triangle. What you're seeing is the whole fur texture tiled densely over the mesh.

You need to supply better texture coordinates.

Comment: Any resources I can refer for doing this ? All I can find is how to map textures onto dumb cubes. :(

Comment: There are many way to obtain/create/generate texture coordinates. In your case I would suggest you need to obtain some data that already has them - I am sure this must exist for a model like the Stanford bunny (the original data is a 3D scan which has none, but it has surely been parameterised since). Otherwise either get a modelling tool which you can use to create them, or start looking into mesh parameterisation.

Answer (score 4):

For a start you can use a simple object space mapping, for example for a (x, y, z) vertex you could use (x*scale, (y+z)*scale) texture coordinates. You can then tweak **scale**.